# Using an interface in Java as a mean to work on a code with more teams

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

I've came into this question and response when trying to prepare for Java OCA exam.

> Imagine you are working with another team to build an application. You are developing code that uses a class that the other team has not finished writing yet. Which element of Java would best facilitate this development, allowing easy integration once the other team’s code is complete?
>
> A.
>   An abstract class
>
> B.
>   An interface

I've answered A but the true answer was B.

The reason was:

> The key here is understanding which of these features of Java allow one developer to build their application around another developer’s code, even if that code is not ready yet. For this problem, an interface is the best choice. If the two teams agree on a common interface, one developer can write code that uses the interface, while another developer writes code that implements the interface. Assuming neither team changes the interface, the code can be easily integrated once both teams are done. For these reasons, Option B is the correct answer.

I don't understand how you can use an interface without implementing it.

Comment: *I don't understand how you can use an interface without implementing it.* - You don't. The good thing interfaces provide is a way to know which methods will be exposed without knowing about the implementation. You can use methods from that interface without caring about what the actual implementation is. When the other team's work is done, they'll just have to provide that implementation, but your code will need almost no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write an abstract class since you don't really want to write code that gets thrown away. The other team will deliver its class eventually, so every effort you put into your abstract class is very likely to be waste.

Implementing a clean interface gives you and the other team a very good idea about what you need, so implementing this should be straight forward.

Answer (score 3):

The key is in "one developer can write code that uses the interface", i.e. you can write code that works on instances of classes that implement this interface and call methods on them without actually knowing what class those instances will be nor any implementation details that could break your code.

So writing code means you can compile it but of course the application won't run unless an implementation is provided. One implementation could be a mockup which is useful for testing purposes and which would be hard to do with abstract classes.

Why would abstract classes be an inferior choice in many cases? One reason would be that a class can only have *one* direct superclass and thus can't inherit from multiple independent abstract classes while implementing multiple independent interfaces is easy. That among other things allows you to reduce coupling because you don't have to put unrelated methods into a single class.

Answer (score 2):

You can develop interface client code (i.e. classes who use the interface) referring to a fake implementation (e.g. an implementation returning fixed data) of the interface while other developers works on real interface implementations and integrate the real implementation when it will be available. You can use fake implementation in order to both run automated tests and run the whole system or use a *mocking library* in order to automate tests.
The core idea, as you said, is to **refer only to abstractions (interfaces) in order to can *substitute* implementations**. Interfaces are better abstractions than abstract classes, due to their *only abstract* nature (indeed abstract classes can have *concrete* partes, interfaces can't).